# Send DropDown value to API Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, https

I have some Data coming from my API and is displayed in a DropDownButton. My problem is I can't send back the selected value to the API when the submit button is pressed.

> Here I do the register HTTP call

```
  Future<Map> register(String name, String email, String budget,
  String currency, String password, String confirmPassword) async {
  final url = "$api/register";

  var body = {
  'name': name,
  'email': email,
  'budget': budget,
  'currency': currency,
  'password': password,
  'confirmPassword': confirmPassword,
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> result = {
  "success": false,
  "message": 'Unknown error.'
  };

  final response = await dio.post(
  url,
  data: body,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  notifyListeners();
  result['success'] = true;

  return result;
 }
 Map apiResponse = response.data;
 _status = Status.Authenticated;

  _token = apiResponse['token'];
  print(_token);
  await storeUserData(apiResponse);

  if (response.statusCode == 422) {
  if (apiResponse['errors'].containsKey('email')) {
    result['message'] = apiResponse['errors']['email'][0];
    return result;
  }

  if (apiResponse['errors'].containsKey('password')) {
    result['message'] = apiResponse['errors']['password'][0];
    return result;
  }

  return result;
 }

 return result;
 }
```

> This is the post function that I'm calling in the UI

```
    Future<void> submit() async {
  final form = _formKey.currentState;
  if (form.validate()) {
    response = await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .register(name, email, budget, currency, password, confirmPassword);
    if (response['success']) {
      print("Signed Up Successfuly");
      showAlertDialogWithActions(
          "Signed Up Successfuly, Please Sign in to continue", context);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        message = response['message'];
      });
    }
  }
  }
```

**DropDown Button**

```
     DropDownInput(
                      validator: (value) {
                        currency = selectedValue;
                        return Validate.requiredField(
                            value, 'Budget is required.');
                      },
                      width: 150,
                      hint: "Currency",
                      items: currencyItemList.map((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(item['currencyName']),
                            value: item['_id'].toString());
                      }).toList(),
                      onChange: (newVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedValue = newVal;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedValue, 
                    )
```

I want to send the **SelectedValue** to API using the **validator** I'm using above

Comment: What is the difference between `selectedValue` and `currency`? Isn't it that in the onChange of your DropDownInput, you should set the `currency` to `newVal`?

Comment: @Gpack I want to store **selectedValue** in Currency so then I can send the currency to the API. isn't that correct?